# How do I manually install GRUB?

Tags: installation, grub2

I was installing Ubuntu 11.10 and the bootloader install failed. I tried installing it again but it didn't work so I want to know how to install grub manually.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think this technique will not work. Because you don't know in which position you installer crashed. Check your disk first.

If you want to install grub manually then:
Login using livecd. Open terminal, login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

find out your linux disk :

```
fdisk -l
```

mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

Recover:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

For more information 
http://shantanucse.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-recover-ubuntu-904-or-higher.html

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases `sudo update-grub` might not work - it happened to me when installing Debian beside Ubuntu.

In such a case I do one of the following:

- Create a live CD/USB of [Ubuntu Secure Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix), which is an Ubuntu live with supplementary rescue tools, boot from that and use **Boot Repair**.
- If you already have a regular Ubuntu live iso, create live usb  with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), live boot from that and install Boot Repair

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
>   update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair &

(But `apt-get update` on a live USB might involve updates that take some time - and are also useless if the live usb is not persistent - so I recommend the first solution.)

Using **Boot Repair** to fix/reinstall GRUB is simple, just choose default/recommended repair option; more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).