# Ubuntu not booting after installation on Acer R5-571T 59DC

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in an Acer R5-571T 59DC notebook for dual booting with the preinstalled Win 10 (UEFI).

After restart there is no GRUB menu and the PC boots directly on Windows.

I disabled secure boot and fast boot before install, and also used "boot repair" with a live usb. No luck.

I managed to start Ubuntu using Super Grub2 Disk, so I think GRUB is ok but without the super grub pendrive I cannot boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you disable "fast startup" in Windows?

Comment: Does the EFI boot menu (some function key at power-up) give you an ubuntu entry?  Does it work?

Comment: fast startup was disabled in Windows and in EFI boot menu only was Windows.

Comment: Now after enabling secure boot  the option for adding Ubuntu to the   EFI boot menu was enabled. The pc is still starting windows directly but I can stop it with the F12 key to show the menu and start GRUB

Answer (score 1):

I found a good enough solution.

I enabled secure boot again in the UEFI settings and after that the option for adding the new OS to the EFI boot menu was enabled.

Now when I access it with <kbd>F12</kbd> key I have both the Ubuntu & Windows options.

Thanks wjandrea for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade, update the system, and install grub. After that your problem will get solved.

For update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For installing grub, follow this link  [How do I manually install GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74761/how-do-i-manually-install-grub)