# Recovery formatted files files after installing Windows on ubuntu hard drive

Tags: boot-repair

I tried installing windows 10 in ubuntu hard drive without backing up files in the ubuntu hard drive. Now while installing windows, I cancelled the installation which means I didn't allow the windows 10 to install completely. After this, I've not been able to boot into ubuntu again and I have important files on it. Please what can I do to recover those files.

Comment: Sorry the files are gone.

Comment: You can try and plug the drive into another machine and see if any ghost files remain, although if I remember correctly, Windows reformats the partitions it needs and as such, files may be unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you installed Windows, the Ubuntu partition may or may not be overwritten. If you allowed Windows to overwrite the disk, the situation will be bad. The directory structures then are overwritten and you can rescue some data only with recovery software. The biggest chance is then relying on an expensive professional data recovery service.

If you installed Windows in a dedicated partition, then the Ubuntu partition will be untouched. Boot a live DVD or USB session, where you can you can access the partition and copy the data elsewhere.

In the latter scenario, you could make the system bootable again by [reinstalling grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74761/how-do-i-manually-install-grub).